# Rspec / FactoryBot factories are not running after_initialize when createing a new instance in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have some models that use an `after_initialize` hook like so to set a load of default attributes and other things:

```
after_initialize do |some_model|
  initializer(some_model)
end

def initializer(some_model)
  #... loads of pre-processing
end
```

This all runs great in development and production, however in my FactoryBot and rspec tests this hook isn't running. I have a factory that looks like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :some_model do
    some_number { 1 }
    is_it_something { false }
    account { create(:user).accounts.first }
  end
end
```

But my tests are looking like this:

```rb
some_model = create(:some_model)
some_model.initializer(some_model)
```

The issue is I'm having to call the `initializer` seperatly after creating the FactoryBot model. This is causing all sorts of issues because the `create()` triggers the create validations, and they fail because the initializer isn't ran.

How can I get FactoryBot to run `after_initialize` when creating a new instance?

Thanks.

(I might have got some terminology wrong here, so please correct me if I have.)

Comment: If you are using Rails 5+ you can use the attributes API to set defaults instead of using callbacks which make your life hell. https://metova.com/rails-5-attributes-api/

Comment: I've tried this but they don't quite do what I'm looking for in this case.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem with the code you provided, can you provide minimal reproducible scenario. In my case it is running the `after_initialize` with `build` and `create`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `after(:build)` callback of the factory to call the initializer since factorybot sets the attributes after initialization.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :some_model do
    some_number { 1 }
    is_it_something { false }
    account { create(:user).accounts.first }
    after(:build) do |some_model|
      some_model.initializer(some_model)
    end
  end
end
```

that way you don't have to call it every time you create new object from the factory

Anyway, this `initializer` method looks like a code smell. I'm not sure what does it do, but maybe there's a better way to do that that also prevents this problem.

Answer (score 2):

FactoryBot calls setters for attributes, not the constructor, so `build :some_model, some_attribute: 123, other_attribute: :foo` is in fact equivalent of:

```rb
SomeModel.new.tap{|m|
  m.some_attribute = 123
  m.other_attribute = :foo
}
```

This way initializer is called on a empty object and only after that all other attributes are getting set.

When you need to set some attributes that are dependent on others - i'd opt into custom setters like

```rb
def some_other_attribute=(val)
  self.some_attribute = calculate(val)
  super
end
```

or do it in `before_validation`